# Match two nodes and keep the path between the other respective nodes networkx

Tags: python, graph, networkx

### EDITED

df1

```
From   description    To      priority 
10        Start      20,30       1
20        Left       40          2 
30        Right      40          2
40        End        -           1
```

My second data frame

df2

```
From   description    To      priority 
50        Start      60,70       1
60        Left       80          2 
70        Right      80          2
80        End        -           1
```

When I convert the two data frames into graph using `Netwokrx` Python library, I get the following graphs as graph1 for df1 and graph2 for df2. The color of the nodes is based on their priority.

[image]

I would like to match (combine) two nodes which have similar color such as 10/50, 40/80, 20/60, and 30/70. Just to make it clear, 10 and 50 have `Start`  attribute and 40 and 80 have `End`. In addition to these, 10, 50, 40, and 80 have `priority ==1` attribute. Node 20 and 60 have '''Left' attribute and 30 and 70 have `Right`. In addition to these, 20, 60, 30, and 70 have `priority ==2`.

I managed to match nodes at once for the whole nodes in the two graphs. But I couldn't manage to go step by step (using a kind of loop). Which means first match nodes with `blue` color then add one of the nodes with `orange` color and so on.  I would expect something like below.

[image]

To achieve the above result, this how I tried.

```
for n1, n2 in g1.nodes(data ='True'):
    for x1, x2 in g2.nodes(data ='True'): 
        if ((g1.node[n1]['description']) == (g2.node[x1]['description'])&
            if ((g1.node[n1]['priority']) == (g2.node[x1]['priority'])
             ):
            name1 = str(n1) + '/' + str(x1)
            mapping1 = {n1: name1, x1:name1}
            mapping1 = nx.relabel_nodes(g1, mapping1, copy =True)
```

Can anyone extend the above trial or find a new solution to get what I would like to see?

Comment: How do you know which nodes should be mapped? E.g. why is 10/50 created and not 10/80?

Comment: @Sparky05 Thanks for the reply. Since it is a directed graph, ```10 and 50``` are starting node and they have ```Start``` attribute. And ```40 and 80``` have ```End``` attribute.

Comment: Could you add a full example of your graphs with all your data to the question? Then it's easier to help you

Comment: @Sparky05 I have just edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the following code you can relabel the nodes:

More hints to the [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) function.

```py
import networkx as nx

df1_graph = nx.DiGraph()
# add edges
df1_graph.add_edges_from([(10, 20), (10, 30), (20, 40), (30, 40)])
# add node information
nodes = [10, 20, 30, 40]
descriptions = ["Start", "Left", "Right", "End"]
priorities = [1, 2, 2, 1]
for node, (description, priority) in zip(nodes, zip(descriptions, priorities)):
    df1_graph.nodes[node]["description"] = description
    df1_graph.nodes[node]["priority"] = priority

df2_graph = nx.DiGraph()
# add edges
df2_graph.add_edges_from([(50, 60), (50, 70), (60, 80), (60, 80)])
nodes = [50, 60, 70, 80]
for node, (description, priority) in zip(nodes, zip(descriptions, priorities)):
    df2_graph.nodes[node]["description"] = description
    df2_graph.nodes[node]["priority"] = priority

# creating new graph
mappings = []
for node_1, data_1 in df1_graph.nodes(data=True):
    for node_2, data_2 in df2_graph.nodes(data=True):
        if data_1["description"] == data_2["description"] and data_1["priority"] == data_2["priority"]:
            name = str(node_1) + '/' + str(node_2)
            # add found mapping (node_1, name)
            # together with information about sorting order
            mappings.append((data_2["priority"], data_2["description"], node_1, name))

new_graph = df1_graph.copy()
# save the relabelled graphs in a lists
graphs_stepwise = []
# sort nodes according to priority and description (secondary key)
# we sort first by description to ensure in this example Left is replaced first
mappings = sorted(mappings, key=lambda x: x[1])
# sort by priority
mappings = sorted(mappings, key=lambda x: x[0])
# relabel one node at a time
for priority, description, node, new_label in mappings:
    new_graph = nx.relabel_nodes(new_graph, {node: new_label}, copy=True)
    graphs_stepwise.append(new_graph)

# print node information of saved graphs
for graph in graphs_stepwise:
    print(graph.nodes(data=True))
    #[(10, {'description': 'Start', 'priority': 1}), (20, {'description': 'Left', 'priority': 2}), (30, {'description': 'Right', 'priority': 2}), ('40/80', {'description': 'End', 'priority': 1})]
    #[('10/50', {'description': 'Start', 'priority': 1}), (20, {'description': 'Left', 'priority': 2}), (30, {'description': 'Right', 'priority': 2}), ('40/80', {'description': 'End', 'priority': 1})]
    #[('10/50', {'description': 'Start', 'priority': 1}), ('20/60', {'description': 'Left', 'priority': 2}), (30, {'description': 'Right', 'priority': 2}), ('40/80', {'description': 'End', 'priority': 1})]  
    #[('10/50', {'description': 'Start', 'priority': 1}), ('20/60', {'description': 'Left', 'priority': 2}), ('30/70', {'description': 'Right', 'priority': 2}), ('40/80', {'description': 'End', 'priority': 1})]
```

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer. Your soultion works fine to get the result found on ```step 3``` above. Is that possible to iterate step by step. Which means First ```Step1``` then ```Step 2``` then ```Step 3``` and so on. When passing from one step to the next, I would like keep the labeled nodes from the previous steps. For example, in the above sample example, first I would like relabel ```10/50``` and ```40/80``` in the first step. The on 2nd step keep these mapped labels and append the next nodes which are ```20/60```

Comment: I modified my answer to only relabel one node in each step (and respecting the priority).

Comment: Perfect thanks! One more question, what if I want to add more attributes in addition to the one you called ```respecting priority```. For example, to make my mapping more accurate, I would like to add ```description``` as well. My question is here ```mappings.append((data_2["priority"], (node_1, name)))``` .  The other thing is I couldn't understand why created ```graphs_stepwise ``` list. I was trying to create a graph on using this but I think it is a list of nodes. I am just using the ```new_graph ```. Though it seems working. :)

Comment: I've now extended the explanation and added the additional sorting by description (as secondary key). The `graphs_stepwise` are only a list of the created graphs. For example, `graphs_stepwise[1:]` are a list of the three graphs from your step 1, step2 and step 3.